# Python.. image processing

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I need to store histograms of images from a database which can be later used to compare with the histogram of an image given by the user.
The problem: how can I store histograms & how can I compare histograms?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def thresholded(center, pixels):
    out = []
    for a in pixels:
        if a >= center:
            out.append(1)
        else:
            out.append(0)
    return out

def get_pixel_else_0(l, idx, idy, default=0):
    try:
        return l[idx,idy]
    except IndexError:
        return default

img = cv2.imread('006A61.jpg', 0)
transformed_img = cv2.imread('006A61.jpg', 0)

for x in range(0, len(img)):
    for y in range(0, len(img[0])):
        center        = img[x,y]
        top_left      = get_pixel_else_0(img, x-1, y-1)
        top_up        = get_pixel_else_0(img, x, y-1)
        top_right     = get_pixel_else_0(img, x+1, y-1)
        right         = get_pixel_else_0(img, x+1, y )
        left          = get_pixel_else_0(img, x-1, y )
        bottom_left   = get_pixel_else_0(img, x-1, y+1)
        bottom_right  = get_pixel_else_0(img, x+1, y+1)
        bottom_down   = get_pixel_else_0(img, x,   y+1 )

        values = thresholded(center, [top_left, top_up, top_right, right, bottom_right,
                                      bottom_down, bottom_left, left])

        weights = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
        res = 0
        for a in range(0, len(values)):
            res += weights[a] * values[a]

        transformed_img.itemset((x,y), res)

    #print x

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('thresholded image', transformed_img)

hist,bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(),256,[0,256])

cdf = hist.cumsum()
cdf_normalized = cdf * hist.max()/ cdf.max()

plt.plot(cdf_normalized, color = 'b')
plt.hist(transformed_img.flatten(),256,[0,256], color = 'r')
plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.legend(('cdf','histogram'), loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The title of your question is very vague ; improving it increases your question visibility. Something like "saving and comparing histograms in Python" would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use again the `np.histogram` to get the values of the histogram into an array, Then save it to file with `np.save` and load it later with `np.load`. The histogram comparison is then easy. something like `np.linalg.norm(hist1 - hist2)`.
see below (I changed `cv2` to `scupy.misc`/`pyplot` for my convenience).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

pic = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"


def thresholded(center_, pixels):
    out = []
    for a_ in pixels:
        if a_ >= center_:
            out.append(1)
        else:
            out.append(0)
    return out


def get_pixel_else_0(l, idx, idy, default=0):
    try:
        return l[idx, idy]
    except IndexError:
        return default

img = imread(pic, mode='I')
transformed_img = imread(pic, mode='I')

for x in range(0, len(img)):
    for y in range(0, len(img[0])):
        center        = img[x, y]
        top_left      = get_pixel_else_0(img, x-1, y-1)
        top_up        = get_pixel_else_0(img, x, y-1)
        top_right     = get_pixel_else_0(img, x+1, y-1)
        right         = get_pixel_else_0(img, x+1, y)
        left          = get_pixel_else_0(img, x-1, y)
        bottom_left   = get_pixel_else_0(img, x-1, y+1)
        bottom_right  = get_pixel_else_0(img, x+1, y+1)
        bottom_down   = get_pixel_else_0(img, x,   y+1)

        values = thresholded(center, [top_left, top_up, top_right, right, bottom_right,
                                      bottom_down, bottom_left, left])

        weights = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
        res = 0
        for a in range(0, len(values)):
            res += weights[a] * values[a]

        transformed_img.itemset((x, y), res)

    # print x
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('image')
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(transformed_img)
plt.title('thresholded image')

hist, bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(), 256, [0, 256])

cdf = hist.cumsum()
cdf_normalized = cdf * hist.max() / cdf.max()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(cdf_normalized, color='b')
hist_trans, bins_trans = np.histogram(transformed_img.flatten(), 256, [0, 256])
plt.bar(bins_trans[:-1], hist_trans, width=np.diff(bins_trans), color='r')
plt.xlim([0, 256])
plt.legend(('cdf', 'histogram'), loc='upper left')
plt.show()

file = r'd:\temp\1.npy'
np.save(file, hist_trans)

# do something here...

hist_trans1 = np.load(file)
print(np.linalg.norm((hist - hist_trans1)))
```